# Posting multiple elements within an array to API via Python

Tags: python, json, post

I have a Python script that sends POST request to an endpoint to create a keyword and an SMS response. For the POST data I want to post multiple zip codes and receive a specific response for each zip code I post that says "sorry, we're closed"

I tried researching previous questions and got no luck

```
import requests

zip=[21000, 21001]

for i in zips:
    url = "https://myurl.com/keywords"
    payload = "{\n  \"name\":" zip[i],"\n  \"response_text\": \"sorry, we're closed"\n}\n\n"
headers = {
    'X-AUTH-TOKEN': "mytoken",
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "something",
    'Host': "something",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'Content-Length': "140",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I'm getting an invalid syntax error at the zip[i] within the payload.

Comment: please format your code as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you forgot to escape a `"` caracter.
it might be useful to use the json module instead of handcrafting the payload.

```
import requests
import json

zip_codes=[21000, 21001]

for zip_code in zip_codes:
    url = "https://myurl.com/keywords"
    payload = json.dumps({
        "name": zip_code,
        "response_text": "Sorry, we're closed",
    })
    ...
```